# Virtual-Layer/SQL-View: SQL to get list of all values in a group (SpatiaLite/GeoPackage)

Tags: qgis, sql, geopackage, sqlite

**I have** a GeoPackage-Table and it's looking like that:

```
id   data
--   ----
1    A
1    A
1    B
2    A
2    B
3    B
3    B
```

**I need** a virtual layer or a SQL-View that should look like that:

```
id   data
--   ----
1    A, B
2    A, B
3    B
```

But if I use "GROUP_CONCAT":

```
SELECT id, GROUP_CONCAT(data)
 FROM mytable
 GROUP BY id
```

**I get** that:

```
id   data
--   ----
1    A, A, B
2    A, B
3    B, B
```

So is there a function, which gives me the result I wanted?

Comment: This appears to be a pure SQL question, better researched in [dba.se].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per [the docs](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html), built-in Aggregates support the `DISTINCT` operator; simply run

```
SELECT
    id,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT data)
FROM
    mytable
GROUP BY
    id
;
```

---

**For Reference:**

You can achieve the same with a sub-query, i.e.:

```
SELECT
    id,
    GROUP_CONCAT(data)
FROM (
    SELECT
        id,
        data
    FROM
        mytable
    GROUP BY
        id,
        data
) q
GROUP BY
    id
;
```

where the `GROUP BY` inside the sub-query has the exact same effect - and there are cases where this is faster than using `DISTINCT`, mainly whenever a `UNIQUE/PRIMARY KEY` is part of the group keys.

**Note:**

With *SQLite* and `GROUP_CONCAT`, you *have* to use a sub-query if you also specify a `custom_delimiter`, as with `DISTINCT` it will fail with

> DISTINCT aggregates must have exactly one argument